# XML a TXT y vice versa

Tags: xml

Buenas, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de transformar un archivo .XML en uno .txt o a Excel, de forma que pueda ver los datos por columnas y modificarlos, para finalmente volverlo a guardar en el XML.

No he encontrado la forma de guardar desde Excel a XML ya que se producen errores de datos no normalizados, etc... Y no he visto ninguna opción que me deje el XML tal cual estaba.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: el formato .csv que puede exportar excel es un texto plano, lo puedes considerar un txt.